# IE 8 fails to post to mvc 3 when array dynamically appended to a DOM element

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

When dynamically creating a checkbox array with JQuery and appending to a DOM element, IE 8 doesn't submit the checkbox array as part of the form.  It works perfectly fine with Firefox and Chrome.  I'm using the MVC 3 framework on the server side.  Any ideas for a work-around to get this working with IE 8?  I would definitely appreciate any advice.

MODEL:

```
public int[] SelectedTemplateRequirements { get; set; }
```

VIEW:

HTML:

```
<label for="requirementsTemplateDetail">Requirements:</label><br />
<div id="requirementsTemplateDetail"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Fills up the textarea */
    function fillTextArea(ctrlName, list) {
        // clear div
        $('#requirementsTemplateDetail').empty();

        $.each( list, function (index, itemData) {
            // alert(itemData.Id );
            $(ctrlName).append(
                $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
                    name: 'SelectedTemplateRequirements',
                    value: itemData.Id,
                    type:  'checkbox',
                    checked: 'checked'
                })
            ).append(itemData.Name + '<br/><br/>');
        })
    }

  function fillRequirementsDropdown(response) {
    fillTextArea("#requirementsTemplateDetail", response.Reqs);
  }

function postFormRequirementsByTemplateID(ctrlName) {
    var theForm = $(ctrlName).parents('form');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetRequirementsByTemplateID")',
        data: theForm.serialize(), 
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert("An error occurred while saving\n\n" + err);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            fillRequirementsDropdown(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function auditType_SelectionChanged() {
    postFormRequirementsByTemplateID("#AuditTemplateId");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ClassTypeId").change(function () {
        ClassType_SelectionChanged();
    });
    $("#AuditTemplateId").change(function () {
        auditType_SelectionChanged();
    });
    $('#templateSearchID').click(function () {
        auditTemplateButtonPressed();
    });
    $('#templateAllID').click(function () {
        auditTemplateAllPressed();
    });
});

</script>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public class AuditController : ComplianceController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string submit, AuditDocument document )
    {
            // Inserts into AuditRequirementDetail table
            m_activeContract.insertAuditTemplateRequirements(document, myuser);
    }
}
```

What happens is that IE 8 fails to bundle up the `SelectedTemplateRequirements` array since it shows up as `NULL` by the time it gets returned to the post action method on the controller.  Would really appreciate any advice on this since IE 8 still has a large user base.

Comment: Where do you call `fillTextArea()`? What, if any errors are you getting in the console? There are a lot of missing details here. http://jsfiddle.net/gTfjN/1/

Comment: It's called from another JQuery function that breaks up the AJAX response into the separate "index" and "itemData" (a collection) parts.  Where it's called from doesn't really have any significance since the breakdown is happening at the "SelectedTemplateRequirements" array.  It works beautifully with Firefox and Chrome, so something about IE 8 is preventing the "SelectedTemplateRequirements" array from populating the MVC model  when the form is submitted.  It's like IE 8 doesn't even see the dynamically generated html for this list of checkboxes.  Something's screwy with IE 8.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase:  The values within the list of check boxes aren't submitted by IE 8 for some reason when the rest of the form is submitted.. even though it is a part of the form.  Chrome and Firefox submit fine.  Also, I meant to say that the calling function breaks it into the "ctrlName" and "list" (collection) parameters that are passed in.

Comment: You haven't showed enough code to conclude IE8 is the problem. I haven't seen a form, a collection, or much else. This question is lacking a lot of helpful details. Keep in mind that jQuery has been used to submit dynamically-added form-data for a long time now, including in IE8. The problem is most likely *not* the browser.

Comment: If it's not IE 8, how can it possibly work for Chrome and Firefox?  Can you answer that?  When I look at the details of that "document" object passed into the controller class, it shows "SelectedRequirements" as set to NULL.  When I do the same for Firefox/Chrome, it shows the full array passed in.  In other words, Firefox and Chrome can send in that array to the server from the browser, IE 8 can't.

Comment: You're forgetting one crucial item in the equation, *you*. You may have done something in such a way that *some* browsers work in spite of your mistake, while others don't. That is why I wanted to see more of your code, in the off-chance you missed something. There are scores of differences between Chrome, Firefox, and IE that we as developers have to keep in mind.

Comment: There's a lot of code, so I can't possibly include all of it here.  I will include as much of the script code as possible and possibly some controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue may lie within the way you are creating and appending your checkboxes to your DOM elements.

For instance, let's say you have the following code:

```
// Append an input element built from a single string
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="' + i + '" checked="checked" />').appendTo('#form1');
}

// Append an input element build using DOM and jQuery attribute manipulation
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
        name: 'test',
        value: i,
        type: 'checkbox',
        checked: 'checked'
    }).appendTo('#form2');
}

alert($('#form1').serialize());
alert($('#form2').serialize());
```

If you examine the `alert()` results in Chrome or Firefox, you will have this from `#form1`:

```
test=0&test=1&test=2&test=3&test=4&test=5&test=6&test=7&test=8&test=9
```

and this from `#form2`:

```
test=0&test=1&test=2&test=3&test=4&test=5&test=6&test=7&test=8&test=9
```

They are identical, and support your results of having expected behavior in Chrome and Firefox. However, IE does **NOT** behave the same. The same code in IE8 and IE9 produces this from `#form1`:

```
test=0&test=1&test=2&test=3&test=4&test=5&test=6&test=7&test=8&test=9
```

and this from `#form2`:

```
test=on&test=on&test=on&test=on&test=on&test=on&test=on&test=on&test=on&test=on
```

From this brief examination of your code, I would question the method you are using to dynamically create and append the checkboxes to your DOM elements. I don't know how MVC handles the case where every POST variable is identical, but it may be part of your issue.

Another cross-browser way of appending your checkboxes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({
        name: 'test',
        value: i
    }).prop('checked', true).appendTo('#form3');
}
```

You need to make sure that the type is specified before you add the attributes. Also, properly setting the "checked" property is crucial to jQuery serializing the values, not the states, of the checkboxes in IE.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quaeU/2/) of above**.

Comment: You rock!  Thank you for the cross-browser suggestion!  It worked like a charm.

Comment: @TheDude: No problem! It was a shot in the dark but something just didn't look right about the way you were creating your checkbox elements. If this was my app, I'd roll with the code that appends to `#form1` (a nice one-liner), but the last example would be fine as well (pending further testing -- Opera, Safari, etc.). Cheers!